# How to destroy a canvas using Id and add new canvas to the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, charts, chart.js

I am using line and bar charts using Chart.js.  I have 2 options for showing their data: before button click and after button click. Both the cases are working fine. But the issue is that, whenever the button is clicked and the mouse cursor is hovered over the over graph it shows old data(All time).

**Expected outcome:** Chart should no longer has previous data, but instead, shows new data and user can interact with it without issues.

**Actual outcome:** Chart shows new data, but if a user hovers over the chart, it'll flicker back and forth between original and new data

Here is the code

**to display charts**

```
<div ngDraggable class="col-lg-4 my-2 drag-block" *ngFor="let selectedItem of selectedKpi" (edge)="checkEdge($event)"
        [bounds]="myBounds" [inBounds]="inBounds">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
              <h5>{{selectedItem}}</h5>
            </mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>
            <canvas id="{{selectedItem}}">{{chart}}</canvas>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
```

**Typescript code:**

```
this.selectedKpi = ["Clicks", "Orders", "Revenue", "Impressions"];

drawChart(kpi, divId, chartType, isFilled, data, labels, backgroundColor, borderColor) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById(divId);
              const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              this.element = document.getElementById(divId) as HTMLElement;
              this.element.style.destroy;
              this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: chartType,
                data: {
                  labels: labels,
                  datasets: [{
                    tension: 0,
                    label: kpi,
                    data: data,
                    fill: isFilled,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    pointBorderColor: borderColor,
                    pointRadius: 4,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                  }]
                },
                options: {
                  responsive: true,
                  maintainAspectRatio: true,
                  scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        lineWidth: 1
                      }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                      gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        lineWidth: 1
                      }
                    }]
                  },
                  tooltips: {

                    mode: 'x',
                    callbacks: {
                      labelColor: function (tooltipItem, charts) {
                        return {
                          borderColor: borderColor,
                          backgroundColor: borderColor
                        };
                      },
                      labelTextColor: function (tooltipItem, charts) {
                        return '#3e95cd';
                      }
                    }
                  }, legend: {
                    display: false
                  }, emptyOverlay: {
                    fillStyle: 'rgba(74, 100, 100, 0.04)', 
                    fontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)', 
                    fontStrokeWidth: 0       
                  }
                }
              });
            }, 100);
          }
```

please guide me in how to destroy the canvas and redraw it using its ID.

I've create a stackblitz demo as well. Following is the url.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqnxbq

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz demo?

Comment: Should `this.element.style.destroy;` be called, as in `this.element.style.destroy();` ?

Comment: @traktor53 i've tried using this.element.style.destroy(); but got an error saying

ERROR TypeError: this.element.style.destroy is not a function. but

when using this.element.style.destroy; there's no error, but the old charts are shown when hovered over

Comment: Hi @Justcode I've created a stackblitz demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqnxbq is the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common issue when it comes to updating charts. Please add the following code at the start of your `updateCharts(buttonClick: string)` method.

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
        instance.destroy();
      });
```

It will destroy all the previous chart instances before updating. I hope this is what you're expecting.

Comment: Hi @kunal the given solution destroys all the charts. Could you help me out in destroying a single canvas using its canvas id.

Comment: Yes, possible use the code `Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
        if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "yourCanvasId") {
            instance.destroy();
            return;
        }
    });`